# Perl script that has worked with MySQL for years no longer works after upgrading to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, perl, mariadb, dbi

I created this Perl script to update a bunch of CMS installations automatically.  It has worked for years.  Now it is failing when attempting to connect to each of the databases.  This occurred after updating all of the databases from MySQL 5.7 to MariaDB 10.3.  The line it fails on is pretty basic:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($db_str, $user_str, $pass_str);
```

The $db_str is constructed in this line:

```
$db_str = "DBI:mysql:" . $database . ":localhost";
```

If figure it has to be one of two things: Either the connection string needs to be different for MariaDB, or there is a missing Perl library for MariaDB. But I am new to MariaDB, so I do not know.

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: The error I am getting is:

install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 190, <FHANDLE> line 1.
 at (eval 3) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 3, <FHANDLE> line 1.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at ./update_db_local.pl line 50.

Comment: You probably have to reinstall DBD::mysql to have a version that links against the new .so (From within the `cpan` shell, issue `force test DBD::mysql` then `force install DBD::mysql` if and only if the tests succeeded.)

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem: The path to the Perl libs at the top of the script has changed.  This:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

needed to be changed to:

```
#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl
```

It was specific to the setup of the server which may have changed during an update. Thanks!